# Locale.currentlocale not getting expected result?

Tags: ios, swift, nslocale

As i know Locale.currentLocale returns locale details in setting like language and region in mobile settings

But in my case I have selected English language and region United States

Still current locale returns region code
"CN", expected one is "US"

Not sure what I am missing

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in my case I have selected English language and region United States

I think you have selected it by your develop device .

**However**, you may fix the language and region in your Xcode which ignore the actual Settings in your device.

`Product -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> App Region`

Please, go and check the Scheme in your Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @Elevo, when I changed app region settings then it worked but can we use device settings for find out region?

Comment: @VinodJadhav, of course you can, just set "App Region" and "App Language" with "System ...." , then the app installed will go with your Device Settings.